# Is my Spirit (or any other ability resource) rounded up/down?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am looking at the Monk's [The Guardian's Path](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/passive/the-guardians-path) passive ability, which generates 25% more spirit when using a 2H weapon.

My default attacks give me 6 spirit per attack, so how much spirit does this passive give me?

- 7.5 spirit per attack (there's a hidden decimal point)
- 7 spirit per attack (rounded down)
- 8 spirit per attack (rounded up)

I think if they rounded the numbers then this is very inaccruate, so it seems more likely there is a hidden decimal even though my spirit bubble does not show decimal places.

But if it is not rounded, then what happens when you try to cast a 20 cost skill when you have 19.5 Spirit, and your spirit bubble shows 20 Spirit? Unlike the other classes, Spirit does not go up or down over time (unless you have spirit regen skills/abilities)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The decimal point is hidden, but the value is still there.**

I tested with a monk with Guardian's Path, a 2-Hand Staff and no resource regen equips. I used up all my spirit.

[image: Setup]

Then I hit something.

[image: 7 spirit]

Then I hit something again.

[image: 15 spirit]

I continued this experiment through 150 and the results were: 7. 15. 22. 30. 37, 45, 52, 60, 67, 75, 82, 90, 97, 105, 112, 120, 127, 135, 142, 149, 150.

So there's your answer.

Comment: Yay! I guessed right!

Answer (score 2):

I'm betting that the decimal point is hidden until you form a whole number. First attack gives you 7, second attack gives you 8, even though both technically give you 7.5. I can test this when I get home if you like.

Should be as simple as draining a little spirit, mousing over the globe to get an initial number, do 1 attack and record the number, do another attack and record it again.

Try this several times to make sure the result is consistent, and you should have your answer.

EDIT: Tested this at home and arrived at the same conclusion above. It alternates 7-8-7-8-7-8

Comment: That would make the most sense. I started thinking that as I was writing the question, but figured I'd post the question anyways in case I was missing something, or to help others with the same question. Let me know the results if you do test it later at home :)

Answer (score 1):

Some pretty simple testing will show you that your attacks alternate between generating 7 spirit and 8 spirit. But this doesn't make it clear whether the decimal point is tracked but not shown, or if the attacks simply alternate generating whole numbers worth of spirit.

Here's my test to confirm:

Let's start by assuming that attacks alternate between generating exactly 7 and then exactly 8 spirit.

1. Ensure that I am at 0 spirit (not 0.5) by letting it cap out at 150 with [Chant of Resonance](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/passive/chant-of-resonance), then unequipping that passive and casting [Sweeping Wind](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/sweeping-wind) twice.
2. Carefully make 21 attacks without spending any spirit. 20 attacks gets me to 150 with the last attack generating 8 spirit, so the 21st attack should be one that generates 7.
3. Spend all of my spirit by casting Sweeping Wind twice again.
4. Make one more attack. By our assumption, this should generate 8 spirit. But it gave me 7.

**Conclusion:** We have reached a contradiction, so our assumption is wrong. The alternative is that the decimal point is tracked but not displayed, and always rounds down.

Also, to test your second question about being .5 spirit short of using an ability:

5. Repeat step 1 above to get to 0 spirit.
6. Unequip The Guardian's Path to go back to generating 6 spirit.
7. Smack 2 zombies to get to 12 spirit.
8. Reequip The Guardian's Path.
9. Smack another zombie to reach 19.5 spirit.
10. Use [Blinding Flash](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/blinding-flash). My spirit should now be 9.5.
11. Try to use Blinding Flash again, **but I can't**.

**Conclusion:** The availability of your abilities depends on amount of spirit *shown*, regardless of the decimal point behind the scenes.

Comment: Your spirit gain does not alternate between 7 and 8, but instead gives you a flat 7.5 spirit per attack. Since it is always rounded down, this means the first hit would increase your spirit displayed by 7 while the 2nd hit increases your spirit displayed by 8. Your first test's 21st's hit actually generated you 0 spirit, not 7 or 7.5, which is why after you spent it all and hit something once, it showed you had 7 spirit (although actually you had 7.5)

Comment: Exactly. That's what my test proved.